# ElasticSearch: I am struggling with lowercase when the query has a wildcard surrounded by other characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 5.1.1 installed on a Windows server. I'm doing my testing using Kibana v5.1.2.

My field "p.code_lower" is defined like so:

```
{
  "unittest_catalogdata": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "properties": {
          "p": {
            "properties": {
              "code_lower": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "sort_field": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "analyzer": "lower_keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where my Analyser is defined like so:

```
"analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
        "lower_keyword": {
            "filter": "lowercase",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

The following values indexed in p.code_lower:

```
Cab.B30
Cab.B40
Cab.B50
Cab.B100
Cab.B120
```

*Note that the analyzer is "keyword" + "lowercase" because we need to be able to do a query where `"p.code_lower:cab.b30"` return a result. Since there is a dot inside our code, this is the only way we found to make ElasticSearch work for that field.

---

This Query returns 0 result:

```
GET /unittest_catalogdata/_search
{
          "query": {
          "query_string": {
          "query": "p.code_lower:Cab.B?0",
          "lenient": true,
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
    }
}
```

But this query (notice the lowercases) returns 3 codes (Cab.B30, Cab.B40, Cab.B50)

```
"query": "p.code_lower:cab.b?0",
```

This query (Uppercases, but no field name) returns 3 codes (Cab.B30, Cab.B40, Cab.B50):

```
"query": "Cab.B?0",
```

This query returns all 5 codes as expected:

```
"query": "B*",
```

But this doesn't:

```
"query": "p.code_lower:Cab.B*",
```

Yet this works (lowercased again):

```
"query": "p.code_lower:cab.b*",
```

What could be done to have a case insensitive query where `p.code_lower:Cab.B?0` will work whether the searched characters are lowercase or uppercase? All this while preserving the ability to search with a query containing a dot, i.e.: `p.code_lower:Cab.B30`

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with default analyzer(`standard`). It preserves dot. and should work as you expected.

Comment: Thank you, you were right! I complicated things for nothing.